# Remove div based on child element using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of divs similar to the following:

```
<div class="row"><a data-card-uid="not me"></a></div>
<div class="row"><a data-card-uid="not me"></a></div>
<div class="row"><a data-card-uid="THIS ONE"></a></div>
<div class="row"><a data-card-uid="not me"></a></div>
<div class="row"><a data-card-uid="not me"></a></div>
<div class="row"><a data-card-uid="not me"></a></div>
```

I'd like to remove the div which has

```
data-card-uid="THIS ONE"
```

How can I do this? I understand you can use .remove() to remove the corresponding div but I'm not sure how to select the appropriate one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First select the element whose parent you want to remove using the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), then call `remove()` on the `parent()`.

```
$('[data-card-uid="THIS ONE"]').parent().remove();
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it more specific? For example if the row div is inside a table div like this? <div class="table">row divs are here</div>

Comment: Sure, you can extend the selector. E.g. `div.table > div.row > [data-card-uid="THIS ONE"]` (`>` selects only the immediate children—you might want to omit this)

Comment: use `a` in the selector to improve performance. `$('a[data-card-uid="THIS ONE"]')` Otherwise the JS engine needs to look at every element on the page.

Comment: @sixfingeredman Should be `a[data-card-uid="THIS ONE"]`, not `div`.

Comment: Yep, updated my comment. Was looking at the wrong one. Even better would be to use `querySelector()` if only one match is desired. That way it'll quit after the first one is found.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete the div with the content has data-card-uid="THIS ONE" use:

```
$('[data-card-uid="THIS ONE"]').parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the parent. So

```
$('[data-card-uid="THIS ONE"]').parent().remove();
```

See it here
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dnjg63mj/)

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-card-uid="THIS ONE"]').parent(".row").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <a data-card-uid="not me">not me</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <a data-card-uid="not me">not me</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <a data-card-uid="THIS ONE">this one</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <a data-card-uid="not me">not me</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <a data-card-uid="not me"></a>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <a data-card-uid="not me">not me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why downvote ? Is it not better to specify which parent to remove.Who knows how the structure of page changes in future. It is better to be specific from beginning.